# How to define pattern and allow pattern to repeat only when pattern is broken

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

I'm trying to write a JavaScript regular expression to only allow the following inputs:

- Numbers
- Numbers with commas in between
- Numbers with hyphens in between, but only followed by another number or a comma, followed by a number. This pattern can repeat again.

So far, I have the following expression:

```
^[0-9]$|^[0-9]+$|^[0-9](-?,?[0-9])*$
```

However, this is allowing `1-1-1`, which I do not want. A hyphen can only appear if not followed by another number-hyphen-number combo.

This link might help: http://regexr.com?34ljt

The following samples should evaluate as being valid:

> 01,03,05-08,10
>   01,03,05
>   01,03,05-08
>   01
>   1,1,5-6,1,1
>   1,1,5-6,1,1-3
>   12,12,1-9
>   1-9,5,5
>   1-9,9,9,5-6
>   1-2
>   11-11
>   11,11
>   1,1
>   1,1,1
>   11,11,11
>   1111
>   1,1,1,1,1,1
>   1
>   56,1
>   1,1
>   1,3
>   1,3,4,5
>   1,3

The following samples should evaluate as being invalid:

> sdfdf
>   11-11-11-11
>   1-1-1-1-1
>   f
>   01,
>   01,03,05-08,
>   -1,4-,-5,8909
>   1,1,1-1-1
>   1,1,11-1111-1
>   1-1-1
>   1,,1
>   1--1
>    1-
>   1,,
>   ,-1-
>   df
>   -1
>   ,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
/^\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$/
```

*Further to the comments*

One way to prevent a match if there are consecutive ranges is to add a negative look-ahead

```
(?!.*-\d+,\d+-)
```

so the regex becomes

```
/^(?!.*-\d+,\d+-)\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$/
```

If the pattern inside the negative look-ahead can be matched it prevents the whole regular expression from matching. The `.*` is used so that if e.g. `-1,1-` is found anywhere ahead in the string, a match will be prevented.

Comment: You should definitely add explanation about that regex pattern. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177757/are-answers-that-just-contain-a-regex-pattern-really-good-answers)

Comment: @HugoDozois. You should avoid comments that begin _"You should..."_. For very localised questions such as this, explanation is on request. I note that you didn't make the same comment to the other answer - the one using a look-ahead and garnering the votes.

Comment: I'm sorry didn't want to sound rude. But I stumble on that post from a queue and I didn't see other answers. And it happened that it was seconds after looking at the precise post on the meta that I linked .

Comment: @lymber. Well, from your question it looks like you already have some understanding of grouping `()`, making something optional `?`, the zero or more `*` and one or more `+` quantifiers, and the anchors `^` and `$`. The `\d` (digit) is equivalent to `[0-9]`. I started with the basic structure required which is `\d+(,\d+)*` - a number followed by a comma and another number zero or more times - and then added an optional _group_ `(-\d+)?` so each number could be followed by a `-` and a number.

Comment: so how would you prevent the following 1,1,1-1,1-1 <br/> so that you can only have number hypen number if there is not one of these before?

Comment: yes the regex allows that. so instead of 1,1,1-1,1-1. It should only allow a number-number if there is a number with a comma in between. So this is allowed. 1,1,1-1,5,1-1 because there is a ,5, in between the two hyphened numbers. So how to prevent consecutive 1-1,1-1. So it should only be allowed if 1-1,5,1-1 that way it is not consecutive anymore.

Comment: @lymber. I have added to my answer regarding your new question.

Comment: you guys are the regex gurus! so the .* means. Match any character zero or more times?

Answer (score 3):

Nice link, and kudos for giving enough examples to thoroughly determine whether a solution is correct. This seems to work:

```
^([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?(,(?!$)|$))+$
```

http://regexr.com?34lk6

So: numbers, optionally followed by a dash and more numbers, followed by either a comma (unless the comma is the last character before the end of line) or end of line.

Comment: wow how did you figure this out, how long did it take you? Could you break it down?

Comment: how would you prevent the following 1,1,1-1,1-1<br/>so that you can only have number-number if there is not one of these before?

Comment: @lymber: makes it a lot bigger, it would be _"pattern without - zero or more times, pattern with - 0 or 1 time, pattern without - zero or more times, at least one pattern should match"_, or: `^(?!$)(\d+(,(?!$)|$))*(\d+-\d+(,(?!$)|$))?(\d+(,(?!$)|$))*$` (see: http://regexr.com?34m2q)

Comment: Note BTW that how more complex the pattern becomes, how more attractive it becomes to `split()` on `,` instead and validate the parts.

Comment: hey your regex failed with the following valid patterns: 1,1,5-6,1,1-3<br/>1-9,9,9,5-6

Comment: How does it fail? There's 2 number-number's in there, so they're invalid, which this correctly picks up as invalid?

Comment: they are allowed, but as long as they are not consecutive. they are in the allowed list i provided

Comment: Aha, I intpreted _"only have number-number if there is not one of these before"_ as, well, not allowing anyone before there in the whole string, not just right before the comma. In that case `^(\d+(-\d+(?!,\d+-))?(,(?!$)|$))+$` works: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?34m6f

Comment: hey now that works! But i dont get the following group: (,(?!$)|$))+ could you please explain?

Comment: Every number (or number-number) is folowed by either `,` which is not followed `(?!....)` by end-of line `$`, or in instead of a comma not followed by end of line `|` it is followed by the end of the lineb `$`. So, in essense: there need to be comma's after them, except after the last one. It's called a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Oh, and the final `)+` is just from the beginning of that regex: we need 1 or more numbers